# to display the image based on tag in UIButton in objective-c

Tags: ios

code:
secondviewcontroller:.m file

```
 NSArray *dict;
     dict=[[NSArray alloc]init];
       dict= _array;
         UIImage *colorimage = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
       [_b1 setBackgroundImage:colorimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         UIImage *colorimage1 = [dict objectAtIndex:1];
       [_b2 setBackgroundImage:colorimage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In .h file

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b1;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b2;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b3;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b4;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b5;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b6;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b7;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b8;
   @property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *b9;
```

in firstviewcontroller:
.m file

```
 nnn=[[mem_test alloc]init];
        nnn.array = [randomImageArray mutableCopy];
        [self presentViewController:nnn animated:YES completion:nil];
```

here the data passes to secondviewcontroller.
i need based on the tag of UIButton how to do display the image in UIButton .

this is the code used in UIImageView:

```
for (int j = 1 ; j <=b ; j++){

        subView = [self.view viewWithTag:j];
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            ((UIImageView *)subView).image = selectedImage;



        }
    }
```

So,similar i need to display...

Comment: what is problem you are facing?? what is your dict??

Comment: need additional code

Comment: there is no tag, how you want to decide about image?

Comment: can you add your buton code

Comment: i understand can you add button action code

Comment: can you print the code of dict

Comment: yes can you print once

Comment: Printing description of self->dict:
<__NSArrayM 0x60000004cc90>(
<UIImage: 0x608000091620>, {300, 300},
<UIImage: 0x600000093510>, {640, 480},
<UIImage: 0x600000093290>, {1024, 768},
<UIImage: 0x608000091940>, {1920, 1200},
<UIImage: 0x608000090ea0>, {640, 480}
)

Comment: i need to display the image based on the tag of the uibutton

Comment: can you show the button action code

Comment: @teena - ya I  understand but what the problem u faced, I seen last 1 week you struggle more for this concept,but your ? is not clear to answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need while viewdidload

Comment: what is `j` count

Comment: suppose b=5 then i assign int j=1 then enter to loop and then print 5 times images in uiimageview

Comment: but your total UIbutton count is 4 or else

Comment: sorry i have 9 uibuttons in .h file

Comment: @teena - your concept is not clear, but I got it how to give the OP,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have edited ,please check

Comment: @teena - randomIndex1 and num you get the same index or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my concept is:5 images are stored in dict array.And i have given 9 uibuttons in uiview,aslo i given tag from 1,2,....9.so first i need to select randomly 5 tag values from1,2,...9. so in this tag this 5 images should display.how to do

Comment: @teena - simple then why you taken struggle, then what is the use of `arc4random` in here already you have a button tag correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir,arc4random is for other purpose.so how to do this code as i told my logic

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can u give the steps to do

Comment: @teena - sure, final one doubt and little confuse , in your each button are you  set the image from that dict array or both are different

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  in this code :i just try to get the images.-----UIImage *colorimage = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
       [_b1 setBackgroundImage:colorimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];      i

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need to use in project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir,if u knows then how to do

Comment: ya but little bit confused